# Initialize a set number of variables using C

Tags: c, variables

I have been studying programming for a few weeks, and decided to create a program that needs to initialize a number of variables based on the input from a user. I thought of using some kind of for loop like the one below, but couldn't figure out how.

```
int varnum;
scanf("%d", &varnum);
for(int i = 0; i < varnum; i++){
      int (name of variable goes here)
}
```

Is it possible to do it like this? Or is there a better method?

Comment: As a VLA, zero it: `int x[varnum]; memset(&x, 0, sizeof x);` instead of `for .. { }`.  `x` valid until end of block.

Comment: You can't create variables dynamically in C. Use an array.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible;  not the way you would like (and in any case that syntax would lead to varnum variables that would exist only within the for. You could use an array; I suggest a dynamically allocated one rather than a VLA (variable length array).